# Shear force diagram and bending moment diagram for Semicircular beam of uniform cross section

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

The question goes as:
"Write Equations for axial shear force and bending moment. Draw Shear force diagram and bending moment diagram for the beam shown.Semicircular beam is of uniform cross section."
I attempted the sum by myself, trying to do it from the concept applied on linear beams which is given in most of the books on Engineering Mechanics and Strength of Material/Mechanics of solids. But I am getting confused on how to find the shear force and bending moment at each point of the beam. Please help.  [image: Figure]

Here is my working:

[image: My Working]

Comment: So show what you have completed so far, then people may help checking your work.

Comment: Ok, I have now added my working above.

Comment: Due to the presence of a horizontal component of the thrust at every point of the arch, it is unstable as the displacement of the roller can't be prevented, thus no practical solution exists.  You should double-check whether it is a "two-hinged" arch or a "three-hinged" arch. which behaves quite differently.